# Transform GET parameters to clean URL

Tags: symfony, routes, datatables, silex

I use Datatables on fronted to send GET parameters to my Silex application.

Datatables send GET parameters of that type:

```
champs_societes%5B%5D=naf&zone-geographique=ville&effectif%5B%5D=eff_1a9&effectif%5B%5D=eff_10a19&effectif
%5B%5D=eff_20a49&effectif%5B%5D=eff_plus5000&ca%5B%5D=10k-50k&ca%5B%5D=50k-100k&ca%5B%5D=1kk-2kk&ca%5B
%5D=2kk-5kk&champs_societes%5B%5D=capital_int&fondation%5Bmin%5D=&fondation%5Bmax%5D=&champs_societes
%5B%5D=siren&champs_societes%5B%5D=siret&champs_societes%5B%5D=nature&nature%5B%5D=Etablissement&champs_societes
%5B%5D=formejur&champs_societes%5B%5D=emailg&champs_contacts%5B%5D=emailn&ac_formejur=Artisan-Commer
%C3%A7ant%2CBanque+Populaire%2FLoi+Mars+1917%2CCoop.+%C3%80+Responsabilit%C3%A9+Limit%C3%A9e&ac_naf=0113Z
%2C0121Z%2C0126Z%2C0130Z&ac_departements=14%2C50%2C61%2C68%2C03&ac_villes=77330%2C77680%2C77340&ac_fonction
=Assistant%2CCharg%C3%A9+D'Affaires%2CContr%C3%B4leur+De+Gestion%2CDirecteur+%2F+Responsable
```

I there a way to genereate a clean URL from this chain ? Ideally by using the Symfony/Silex routing.

Thanks for help

EDIT

I get the GET params above with Request:

```
$app->post('/ajax/formprocess', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $df = new Filtres( $request->request->get('dataForm') );

    $filtroAdd = $df->getRequest();
```

Comment: I edited my answer, I believe your problem has nothing to do with Request after all and it's just string parsing

Answer (score 0):

#### I would try with Request class first

`Request` class from HttpFoundation component (default in Symfony, not sure about Silex as I never used it)

```
/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
 */
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
    $request->getBasePath();
    $request->getQueryString(); // this will be the most helpful in your case

    // access what you need and build normalized url
}
```

You should be able to build clean normalized url

#### Edit, solution for parsing query parameter string to array

```
$queryParameters = 'query parameters as string to be parsed';
$output = [];

parse_str($queryParameters, $queryParameters);

print_r($queryParameters);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: I get the GET chain parameters above with $request->get('dataForm') in my controller. But none of the the methods getSchemeAndHttpHost, getBasePath, getQueryString return something. getQueryString('dataForm') returns NULL

Comment: if `getQueryString()` returns nothing then I think you are not using Routing/Controller/Request correctly. Could you include code snippet how you read that?

Comment: @Macbernie I have awful feeling that those are not GET query parameters you try to read but actually POST body. In question you mentioned GET. You should search for solution that will convert string with escaped query parameters into array